# How to update Bash custom prompt to display git status and refresh after file and folder changes?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I added to the `~/.bashrc` a PS1 with changes to the bash prompt so it also shows git branches and status, but if i'm in not a folder with git and goes to one in the terminal, it won't run that PS1 ( because when I opened the terminal it wasn't on a git folder )

Same goes to when i'm in a git folder ( showing the branche and status ), if I make changes or commits it doesn't change the status of git in it.

This is the relevant code from my `.bashrc`.

```bash
tput sgr0;
reset=$(tput sgr0);
white=$(tput setaf 15);
violet=$(tput setaf 61);
green=$(tput setaf 64);
purple=$(tput setaf 125);
yellow=$(tput setaf 136);

prompt_git() {
    local s='';
    local branchName='';

    # Check if the current directory is in a Git repository.
    git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &>/dev/null || return;

    # Check for what branch we’re on.
    # Get the short symbolic ref. If HEAD isn’t a symbolic ref, get a
    # tracking remote branch or tag. Otherwise, get the
    # short SHA for the latest commit, or give up.
    branchName="$(git symbolic-ref --quiet --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || \
        git describe --all --exact-match HEAD 2> /dev/null || \
        git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || \
        echo '(unknown)')";

    # Check for uncommitted changes in the index.
    if ! $(git diff --quiet --ignore-submodules --cached); then
        s+='+';
    # Check for unstaged changes.
    elif ! $(git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules --); then
        s+='!';
    # Check for untracked files.
    elif [ -n "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)" ]; then
        s+='?';
    # Check for stashed files.
    elif $(git rev-parse --verify refs/stash &>/dev/null); then
        s+='$';
    else
        s+='-';
    fi;

    echo -e "\[${white}\] on \[${violet}\]${branchName} \[${purple}\][${s}]";
}

PS1="\[\033]0;\W\007\]";
PS1+="\[${green}\]\w";

PS1+="$(prompt_git)";

PS1+="\[${white}\]: $ \[${reset}\]";
export PS1;

PS2="\[${yellow}\]→ \[${reset}\]";
export PS2;
```

I would like to know if there is a way to "refresh" the PS1 when there is folder changes, git commands and if possible file changes to update the status and branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading about bash strings it looks like double quotes get evaluated before its saved, and single ones evaluate later.

So with that in mind I changed to this and it works:

```bash
# prompt_git
echo -e "${violet}${branchName} ${purple}[${s}]";

# after
PS1+="\[${white}\] on ";
PS1+='$(prompt_git)';
```

But still would be cool if file changes could also change the status itself.